# is something being returned when post-increment (i.e. result++, x++, y++) is used even without the keyword return in front

Tags: java

I am confused with the explanations (at the very bottom: "Choice two will return result regardless... means that first result is returned, then result is incremented") for this flow-chart diagram:
[image]
[image]

I am confused how does the block of code inside (if (num!=0)) in choice 2 works? and also why choice 3 is not the correct answer?

In the answer of choice 2, the part of the code result++, I googled that result++ means result is first returned, then result = result + 1 happen.

So then why does it corresponds correctly to the flow-chart diagram?

The flow-chart says if (num!=0) is true, then result++ is called and then "return result". But there is no explicit result statement in the result++. So does it mean result is returned first, and then after increment, it get "returned" again? so there are 2 return statements? so the flow-chart is still correct (as the sequence of call is still correct). But there is just another return statement right before the result++ increment that is not shown?

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand what does `return` keyword mean? It marks an exit point of a function. Flow inside a functions ends when it encounters `return` and the result of a function is a value next to the `return`.

What you read about `result++` returning value first and incrementing it second is a different kind of "return". The author of this explanation meant the return on the level of variable access operation. Like when you do `System.out.println(result)`, the compiler/interpreter/whatever returns the value of `result` to `println`. `System.out.println(result++)` means `result` is "returned" (perhaps "accessed" would be a better wording), so the function receives it in the initial state, and then it's incremented (`results += 1`).

I think usage of word "return" in context of variable read access was source of your confusion. To return, in a context of a function flow control, means ceasing it and setting a value as its result. When you access a variable in any way, it's also being returned **to you by the compiler**. Does it make more sense to you now?

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question:

```java
result++;
```

is shorter version of

```
result = result + 1;
```

or

```
result += 1;
```

it's just syntax sugar they are all interchangable **unless you are working with result** of this operation. As for that case:

```
int number = 0;
System.out.println(number++);
// This will pass to System.out.println value of number BEFORE
// it was incremented by 1
// So it will print to console string "0"
```

```java
int number = 0;
System.out.println(++number);
// This will pass to System.out.println value of number AFTER
// it was incremented by 1
// So it will print to console string "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Maks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339033/9997212) is perfect, but I'll try to explain it by showing you some code.

---

> I googled that result++ means result is first returned, then result = result + 1 happen.

It's correct, but if you do `result++` inside a method, this will not return to the *method* caller, but to the *expression* caller.

For example, let's look at the following snippet:

```java
public static void sumTwo(int value) {
    int result = value;
    
    // 1:
    int plusOne = result++;

    // 2:
    return ++result;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    // 3:
    int plusTwo = sumTwo(1);
}
```

This can be interpreted as follows:

**1.** Evaluate `result++` and return its value to `plusOne` (the *expression* caller).

**2.** Evaluate `++result` and return its value to whoever called `sumTwo`.

**3.** Evaluate `sumTwo(1)` by **2.** and return its value to `plusTwo` (the *method* caller).